# Cannot replicate mysql database local connection

Tags: networking, server, java, mysql, eclipse

I am running a Java program comprised in a Eclipse Java project (Mars.2) that requires to insert data in a MySQL-based database. When I execute it in a 32 bits Virtual Machine running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS that has mysql 5.5.55 installed it runs with no problem.

However, when I try to port the project to a host (not a Virtual Machine) that is 64 bits, has Eclipse Oxygen.1 and runs the same Ubuntu distro and has mysql 5.5.58 installed (I had 5.5.57 installed previously, but the issue remains the same) I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:334)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
```

My guess is that the StackOverflow exception is due to trying to establish connections with the database for too many times, so I believe that this is happening because there is some failure in the connectivity with the database.

The `my.cnf` configuration file is exactly the same in both machines (I do not need to change any IP because I am using loopback interface in both cases), so I assume this is unrelated to that. Also, the code that I am using is exactly the same in both cases. Does anybody have an idea of what could be happening?

UPDATE: I have taken several actions to solve this issue but none of them have worked. Among them, I have successfully run the example that is described in http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html in both machines, which makes me think that this issue is not because of either the JDBC connector (both of them worked fine, despite being different versions; they are added to the build path in Eclipse), the operating system differences, the database itself (I have checked the content of several columns in the example and the one that I am using and they are the same) or the MySQL server version (one machine has 5.5.55 and the 64 bits one when the issue happens is 5.5.58, but both of them work fine).

However, I have noticed that if I completely delete the database (by executing DROP DATABASE mydatabase) in both machines I obtain different results. In the one where it works I obtain an exception telling me that the database I am trying to connect to is unknown (makes sense) whereas the other machine delivers the exact same exception, as if the database had never existed in the first place. This also happenes if I alter the name of the database to one that does not exist on purpose (working machine says it is unknown, non-working machine throws the same exception). Could it be an issue related to the permissions that Eclipse has in one of the machines?

Comment: Looks like Java can't find the class for the JDBC implementation. Did you add it to the class path? If it contains a native library, does it include one for the 64-bit platform?

Comment: @hemangi-pithava: Thanks for your various edit suggestions! I just have one criticism: please don't format things as code that are part of natural language, e. g. here “Eclipse Oxygen” is a proper noun occurring in natural language and not a string or name passed to a computer program. `my.cnf` is indeed code because it's not natural language but an artefact of the “language” used to specify path names to a computer.

Comment: i tried the jdbc issue you are mentioning by using a simpler example with the same JDBC route and package. the simpler example works, but the code still doesn´t.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot just copy mysql files from one version to another and expect the databases to work. You need first to export the database:

```
mysqldump -u root -p yourdatabasename > yourdatabase.sql
```

And then in the destination machine, create a new database:

```
CREATE DATABASE mynewdb;
```

and import the dumpted database:

```
mysql -u root -p mynewdb  < yourdatabase.sql
```

Only in this way it is guaranteed that the databse can be migrated between different versions or operating systems.

Comment: I actually run a script to generate the new database in the destination machine to make sure of that. Nevertheless. I have done it the way you mention (which is the orthodox one, I guess) and unfortunately the issue still persists.

Comment: Can you confirm that the database is correctly imported on the new machine? To do so, type `mysql -u root -p` and in the mysql console `use mynewdb` and then `describe` to see whether the tables are correctly imported.

Comment: I´m not sure that I understand what you mean. If I type mysql -u root -p and enter the passwoord to get in the sql menu and then use use mynewdb I get "You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed". But if type describe or describe mynewdb I get an error message related to the syntax of the command in both machines (the one where everything works and the other one).